# Advanced animation with Android

Tags: android, animation, view, drawable

I'm looking for a tutorial/guide/something which explains how create some **advanced** animation with Android.

I know that I can create basic animation with "[View Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)", but I'm looking for something much more complicated like an explosion or a fire burning or a person walking.

What do you suggest as best approach? Shall I use the "[Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/animation.html)" and draw frame by frame or there is a better/faster technique? What do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sprite Animation with Android

Actually we do want a low frame rate walking for this tutorial, just like this.
[image]

you can have [source](http://obviam.net/source_code/animation_walk.tar.gz)

for more [ref here](http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/)